# Is it possible to remove an account from the Gmail app but keep the account on the phone?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have multiple Google accounts, synced to the phone.
For one of them I don't use GMail and have turned off syncing of mail. However the account still appears in the GMail app.
This means sometimes I accidentally send email from that account without realising.

Is it possible to remove an account from the GMail app whilst keeping the account on the phone?

Comment: Don't use official Gmail app. Use other email apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official gmail app uses accounts, provided by Android, so it's impossible. Only if you will use some patched version, what will use private accounts, it possible.

Comment: anyone has a patched version to link?